# How to make passive mobs hostile in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to make a minigame on a map I made and a big part of it are killer bats.
Since bats aren't hostile how do I make them hostile? I tried spawning a zombie riding a bat and making the zombie invisible, but the bat dies and the zombie attacks you. Though I could link both of the mobs health together but I don't know wich command to use for that.

Comment: It has to be on minecraft 1.12

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: You can't make the mob itself hostile (unless you try digging in NMS), but there is another option: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/255319/is-there-a-way-to-make-villagers-aggressive-against-the-player-in-vanilla-minecr

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to make Bats Killers but you can do this thing for a map with Bat Killers:

- Create a new entity with command block (you can find some tutorials on Google)
- Make a Resource Pack where the texture of the Zombie is reversed with that of the Bat (or another monster, whatever)
- Finally, you can just make sure that the Bats attack only in the dark so that the player does not see them

Comment: Are the default entity models available somewhere? Also, this would just create zombies looking like bats, in the best case they just hover a bit above the ground. I think the purpose of this question was to have flying enemies, therefore you could better retexture vexes, but it's still not was the question was about. But the question itself can't be answered in Vanilla, because he because asks for a whole new AI.

Answer (score 0):

what if you tried summoning a mob with a custom name
/summon  ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:'[{"text":"Hostile"}]'}

changed his attack damage to 1 heart
/attribute @e[name=Hostile] generic:attackDamage base set 2

and make him angry (repeat)
/data modify entity @e[name=Hostile] AngryAt set from entity @e[type=player] UUID

this should make any mob even a chicken attack players

you might need to add angertime but i dont know how to do that i think its
/data modify entity @e[name=Hostile] AngerTime set 60
or it's
/data modify entity @e[name=Hostile] AngerTime base set 60